# how would one make multiple text shadows appear in order?

Tags: css

i've tried using `transition: all .4s steps(4, end);` but of course, all the shadows appear in four steps, though i'd like one shadow to appear, then the next, and the next, and so on, in the `.4s`  of the transition

CSS:

```
 a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    transition: all .4s steps(4, end);
    text-shadow: 6px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4), -6px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8), 6px -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2), -6px -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of `transition` is the property to which you want to apply the transition. In your case you have specified `all` and perhaps you should have specified `text-shadow`

Then in `text-shadow` specify only the final state, because you are already asking it to go through 4 steps.

I have checked the code and it seems to work fine:

```
a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    transition: text-shadow .4s steps(4, end);
    text-shadow: 6px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
}
```